# Angular 4 Custom directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make my custom directive that shows or hides an element depending on the value that is passed as an input. So far I have made only the directive but it doesn't work.

hidden-directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[myHidden]' })
export class HiddenDirective {
    @Input() myHidden: string;
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
     if (this.myHidden) {
        console.log('hide');
       renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
     }
    }
}
```

App.html
  `<input type="text" name="val" id="val" [(ngModel)]="val">`
   `<h1 [myHidden]="val">Hidden Welcome</h1>`

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use ngIf or ngClass?  both of those are much simpler and can be used on any element, and can also be conditional on the value passed in from your model

Comment: Try the same code in ngOnInit hook or event better in ngOnChanges

Answer (score 0):

Because your directive is touching the DOM, you should make your modifications once the view is Loaded. use a lifecycle hook for that, why not the last one, `AfterViewInit` :

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[myHidden]' })
export class HiddenDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() myHidden: string;
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      if (this.myHidden) {
        console.log('hide');
        renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
      }
    }
}
```

By the way, a simple `*ngIf` should do the trick, instead of a custom directive.

Comment: It gives me an error - 'Can't bind to 'myHidden' since it isn't a known property of 'h1'. '

Comment: Well it's not my code that give you that, you changed something in your code and now it doesn't work anymore. I just moved your logic to hook instead of the constructor, and the error you have has nothing to do with it.